# EAAccessoryManager notifyObserversThatAccessoryDisconnectedWithUserInfo crashes

Tags: objective-c, eaaccessory, socketscan, socketmobile

My application is crashing randomly while connecting to socket mobile reader it gets disconnected for an unknown reason and it throws the following exception:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000066120beb8
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x190e32f30 objc_msgSend + 16
1  ExternalAccessory              0x19f94cf24 -[EAAccessoryManager _notifyObserversThatAccessoryDisconnectedWithUserInfo:] + 104
2  ExternalAccessory              0x19f94f96c -[EAAccessoryManager _externalAccessoryDisconnected:] + 984
3  CoreFoundation                 0x19238022c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x19237f930 _CFXRegistrationPost + 400
5  CoreFoundation                 0x19237f6ac ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1923eeb9c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1504
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1922c1bf4 _CFXNotificationPost + 376
8  Foundation                     0x192dcb62c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x191271200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1912711c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x191275d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
12 CoreFoundation                 0x192393f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
13 CoreFoundation                 0x192391b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1922c0048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
15 GraphicsServices               0x193d46198 GSEventRunModal + 180
16 UIKit                          0x1982a52fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
17 UIKit                          0x1982a0034 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 MobileHospital                 0x10007b3a8 main (main.m:15)
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1912a45b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: check [EAAccessoryManager _notifyObserversThatAccessoryDisconnectedWithUserInfo:] method.

Comment: Seeing on iOS 11.4.0

Comment: Seeing on iOS 13.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notification delegate was not reset to nil. A fix has been applied at version 10.3.79.